# Displaying UIView with Tab Bar and Navigation Bar in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an app that requires the user to login for full functionality, but will allow the user to skip logging in to browse around.

In my storyboard, I have a UIViewController that acts as the Login screen. When I click the Skip button, it goes onto the next screen.

Here is when I run into problems... I want the screen that pops up when the user presses skip to have a Navigation bar and a Tab Bar. I add those two things in and it works.

In my app delegate file I check to see if the user has skipped the app to go straight into the Menu Screen. The problem is, it just goes to a blank white screen without the navigation bar and the tab bar. It works fine when I press skip, but not when I relaunch the app after closing it.

Here is the code that checks if the user has skipped the login:

```
//Check NSUserDefaults to get the value for skipLogin
     BOOL skipLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kACUserDefaultsSkippedLoginKey];

//Check to see if the user has logged in or has already pressed the skip button.
//If not, show the LoginViewController
     if(skipLogin || [PFUser currentUser]) {
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
     MenuViewController *menuView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuView"];
     self.window.rootViewController = menuView;
     }else{
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
     LoginViewController *loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
     self.window.rootViewController = loginView;
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you adding a `UINavigationBar` and a `UITabBar` directly to the view or are you using a `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I'm using the controllers. I select the MenuView and chose "embed in tab bar" and "embed in navigation bar"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to push the new view controller? 
Maybe the problem is that you are loading the storyboard and you are setting also the rootViewController of the window.

Comment: I've thought about that, I just don't know how to implement that in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the AppDelegate. Is there a way to do that there?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and switched the Initial View Controller to be set to the Menu View and if the user hasn't logged in or skipped login, I just pop up the Login View. It works much better that way.

Thank you guys for your help!